# Some file could not be created, Please close all application, reboot Windows and restart this installation [EF core, .NET core]

Tags: c#, entity-framework, iis, .net-core

We are develop backend on .net core + EF Core and our services run under IIS on web server, The frontend we develop on Swift (app on iPAD)
Our customers to used the server all the time (daytime and nighttime)
We can't stop services on IIS when we have new update patch.

**Question:**

1. How we can **overwrite** dll files on IIS when our customer still used the services.
2. How we can update new update patch on the server and don't stop the application pool / stop services on IIS.
3. We can't use ONE customer per ONE application
   pool, because we have more customers on one server, we can't use this solution.
4. If you have other solutions for resolve on the problem please suggestion with us.

[image]

Best,
UT

Comment: Related issue on https://forums.iis.net/p/1236590/2134821.aspx?p=True&t=636372406810499312

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more appropriate on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I think my question for about IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have 2 servers, with load balancer.
1)Make server 1 Down,update/recycle
2)Make server 1 UP
3)Make server 2 Down,Update/recycle
4)Make server 2 UP OR Down your wish.